# Creating a specific type depending on the data received C#

Tags: c#

I have a small project which I am working on as a beginner in OOP and I would like to ask for some help on a particular problem I encountered.

I have Vehicle class that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CarGarageSoftware
{
    class Vehicle
    {
        public string Lplate
        public string Make;
        public string LMOT;
        public string Esize;
        public string Transmission;
        public string Mileage;
        public string FuleT;
    }

    class PersonalUseCars : Vehicle
    {
    }

    class BusinessCars : Vehicle
    {
        public string CompanyN;
        public string CompanyA;
        public string FleetN;
    }

    class WorkVehicle : Vehicle
    {
        public string CompanyN;
        public string CompanyA;
        public string purpose;
        public string Type;
    }

    class Motobikes : Vehicle
    {
    }
```

And I have an order class that makes orders and I have a constructor in that class that takes data from a text file reads it and creates a new vehicle.

The constructor looks like this:

```
public Order(string ordLine, string vehLine,string[] logLine)
{
    orderDetails = new JobDetails(ordLine);
        
    vehicleDetails = new Vehicle();
    mechanicLog = new WorkLog();

    for (int i = 0; i < logLine.Length; i = i + 2)
    {
        mechanicLog.MakeNewEntry(logLine[i], logLine[i + 1]);
    }

    orderName = $"O_{vehicleDetails.Lplate}_{orderDetails.CustomerName}";
}
```

So I would like to have `vehicleDetails` which is the data to create a specific vehicle type. I would like to know which is the fastest and simplest way I could achieve such a result?

The other classes are the worklog class which looks like this:

```
public class WorkLog
{
    // Variables
    private List<Entry> entryLog;

    // Properties

    // Constructors
    public WorkLog()
    {
        entryLog = new List<Entry>();
    }

    // Methods
    // Creates a new entry in the worklog from a string, used for loading from txt file
    public void MakeNewEntry(string date, string log)
    {
        Entry temp = new Entry();
        temp.timeOfEntry = DateTime.Parse(date);
        temp.entryText = log;
    }

    // Overloaded function for creating an entry manually
    public void MakeNewEntry()
    {
        Entry temp = new Entry();
        temp.timeOfEntry = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your log :");
        temp.entryText = Console.ReadLine();
        entryLog.Add(temp);
    }

    // Print the contents of the log
    public void PrintLog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Work Log: \n");

        foreach (var i in Entries)
        {
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.WriteLine(i.timeOfEntry);
            Console.WriteLine(i.entryText);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }

    // Log return for saving to file
    public List<Entry> ReturnLog()
    {
        return entryLog;
    }
}
```

And here is the full order class

```
class Order
{
    // Variables
    private uint orderId;
    private string orderName;
    private bool orderComplete;
    private float orderCost;

    private JobDetails orderDetails;
    private Vehicle vehicleDetails;
    private WorkLog mechanicLog;

    // Properties
    public uint OrderId
    {
        get { return orderId; }
    }

    public string OrderName
    {
        get { return orderName; }
    }

    // Constructors
    public Order(string ordLine, string vehLine,string[] logLine)
    {
        orderDetails = new JobDetails(ordLine);
        vehicleDetails = new Vehicle();
        mechanicLog = new WorkLog();

        for (int i = 0; i < logLine.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            mechanicLog.MakeNewEntry(logLine[i], logLine[i + 1]);
        }

        orderName = $"O_{vehicleDetails.Lplate}_{orderDetails.CustomerName}";
    }

    public Order(uint id)
    {
        orderId = id;
        orderDetails = new JobDetails();
        vehicleDetails = new Vehicle();
        mechanicLog = new WorkLog();
        orderName = $"O{id}_{vehicleDetails.Lplate}_{orderDetails.CustomerName}";
    }
}
```

Comment: What data in `ordLine`, `vehLine`, or `logLine` says what type of `Vehicle` subclass should be instantiated?

Comment: Assuming you can get a `string vehicleTypeName` from those parameters, then you could have a `class VehicleFactory { public Vehicle? TryCreateVehicle() ) }` which would use a `switch` over `vehicleTypeName` and then extracts the necessary string/text values from the (presumably packed-string) `TryCreateVehicle` arguments and passes them to each `Vehicle` subclass' ctors or properties. Note that you should not have `public` fields, and you need to think about whether your `Vehicle` types should be mutable or immutable. (Personally I prefer immutable types and abhor public mutable properties)

Comment: I don't see why it matters what type of vehicle is for the order. Can you give some examples of what `string vehLine` looks like and how it would indicate what type of vehicle it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to ascertain what exactly you are trying to do here. But I am offering a way to create a `Vehicle` class from a string representation using a static method

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public static Vehicle DefineVehicle(string vehLine)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var order = new Order(
            "Pete Smith_5551234_Fog lights not working",
            "B_Pontiac_XYZ 1234",
            "Aftermarket install");

        order.Vehicle.Transmission = "8SP AUTO";
    }
}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public string Lplate;
    public string Make;
    public string LMOT;
    public string Esize;
    public string Transmission;
    public string Mileage;
    public string FuleT;

    protected Vehicle(string make, string lplate)
    {
        Make = make;
        Lplate = lplate;
    }

    public static Vehicle DefineVehicle(string vehLine)
    {
        string[] parts = vehLine.Split('_');

        if (parts.Length > 2)
        {
            string code = parts[0].Substring(0,1);

            switch (code)
            {
                case "P":
                    return new PersonalUseCars(parts[1], parts[2]);

                case "B":
                    return new BusinessCars(parts[1], parts[2]);

                case "W":
                    return new WorkVehicle(parts[1], parts[2]);

                case "M":
                    return new Motobykes(parts[1], parts[2]);

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(vehLine));
    }
}

public class PersonalUseCars : Vehicle
{
    public PersonalUseCars(string lplate, string make)
        : base(make, lplate)
    {
    }
}

public class BusinessCars : Vehicle
{
    public string CompanyN;
    public string CompanyA;
    public string FleetN;

    public BusinessCars(string make, string lplate)
        : base(make, lplate)
    {
    }
}

public class WorkVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public string CompanyN;
    public string CompanyA;
    public string purpose;
    public string Type;

    public WorkVehicle(string make, string lplate)
        : base(make, lplate)
    {
    }
}

public class Motobikes : Vehicle
{
    public Motobikes(string make, string lplate)
        : base(make, lplate)
    {
    }
}

public class MechanicLog
{
    public List<string> Entries;

    public MechanicLog(params string[] log)
    {
        Entries = new List<string>(log);
    }

    public void MakeNewEntry(string line)
    {
        Entries.Add(line);
    }

    public override string ToString()
        => string.Join(Environment.NewLine,Entries);
}

public class OrderDetails
{
    public string CustomerName;
    public string ContactInfo;
    public string Details;

    public OrderDetails(string customerName, string contactInfo, string details)
    {
        CustomerName = customerName;
        ContactInfo = contactInfo;
        Details = details;
    }

    public static OrderDetails GetDetails(string ordLine)
    {
        string[] parts = ordLine.Split('_');
        if (parts.Length > 2)
        {
            return new OrderDetails(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(ordLine));
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle;
    public OrderDetails Details;
    public MechanicLog Log;

    public Order(string ordLine, string vehLine, params string[] log)
    {
        Vehicle = Vehicle.DefineVehicle(vehLine);
        Details = OrderDetails.GetDetails(ordLine);
        Log = new MechanicLog(log);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you for your amazing code, I have some code written already and by adding your suggestion some other parts of the code break, can you have a look at my other classes and suggest your solution, please.

Comment: @DEXTERDEXTER , sorry this is not a code writing service. Please post a new question if you have a new question. I gave you an idea on how to define a _factory_ method to create an instance of a class by processing information.  Also the posts need to specify an example of what inputs are available and any expected outputs.